# The "classical radius" of the electron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electrons

According to one theory, the mass *m* of the electron arises simply as a consequence of the electrostatic energy of its electric field, through Einstein's famous expression ε=*m*c^2, where ε is the field energy and c is the speed of light. The energy of the electron's field is found by integrating the field energy density *U* over all space. If a is the radius of the electron and e is its charge, show that the field energy ε is given by

ε= e^2/8πε0a [where ε0 is the permittivity of free space]

Just some guidance on how to start this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The potential energy integral of an electrostatic $1/r$ potential is infinite. Classical theory can not predict the self-energy of an electron and neither can it predict electron mass. In the standard model of particle physics the electron mass is a parameter of the theory that can also not be derived from anything else (one can express it as function of other physical values, though). The classic electron radius is not a particularly useful concept, since in high energy interactions the electron is completely featureless, so far.

Comment: But it has some historical interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to consider the electron as a spherical shell of radius $r$ with charge $e$, calculate the energy density $u=\dfrac{\epsilon_0E^2}{2}$ of the electric field $E$ and integrate over all space. This energy should be equal to the one given by Einstein's relation $\mathcal{E}=mc^2$. With this equation, you can get the classical radius.